# how to check repetition of a certain number of zeroes following by an equal number of ones in a string?

Tags: c++, string

If user enters a string, i want to make a function to check if a repetition of a certain number of zeroes follows an equal number of ones. Example: 001101 (correct), 01(correct),001010 (incorrect).
I've tried to store the string in 2 separate strings and compare the size but my 2nd while loop isn't stopping.

```
void check(string num) {
    string st0 = "", st1 = "";
    int n = num.length();
    int k = 0;
    
    while (k < n) {
        int i = 0;

        while (num[i] == num[i+1]) {    
            st0.push_back(num.back());
            num.pop_back();
            k++;
            i++;
        }
    
        st0.push_back(num.back());
        num.pop_back();
        k++;
    
        int j = 0;
        while (num[j] == num[j+1]) {
            st1.push_back(num.back());
            num.pop_back();
            k++;
            j++;
        }

        st1.push_back(num.back());
        num.pop_back();
        k++;

        if (st0.size() != st1.size()) {
            cout << "incorrect \n";
        }

        st0.clear();
        st1.clear(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are testing the elements from left to right and you're adding to `st0`  the last elements from `num` string. For example: 
"111010": after the first while `num = "111"` and `st0 = "010"`

```cpp
 while (num[i] == num[i+1]) {    
            st0.push_back(num.back());
            num.pop_back();
            k++;
            i++;
        }
```

And to fix you should add the first element tested not the last.

```cpp
while( num[i] == num[i+1] && i+1 < n ){ 
                st0.push_back(num[i]);
                i++;
            }
            st0.push_back(num[i]); 
            i++;
```

You did the same mistake here

```cpp
while (num[j] == num[j+1]) {
            st1.push_back(num.back());
            num.pop_back();
            k++;
            j++;
        }
```

Fix:

```cpp
while( num[i] == num[i+1] && i+1 < n){
             st1.push_back(num[i]); // same here 
             i++;
        }
        st1.push_back(num[i]);
        i++;
```

I used the same `i` here so that we continue looping the string from where we left off in the first while. 
But there is a more optimized solution if you're interested:

```cpp
void check(string num)
{
    int cnt0 = 0 , cnt1 = 0;
    int n = num.length();
    int i=0;
    bool test = true ; 

    while (i<n){
       /* we can use two variables and increment them instead of strings and compare them cauz we are not using the elements we just need the size of them */
            while( num[i] == num[i+1] && i+1 < n ){ 
                cnt0++ ;
                i++;
            }
            cnt0++;
            i++;
            while( num[i] == num[i+1] && i+1 < n) {
              cnt1++;  
              i++;
            }
            cnt1++;
            i++  ;
            if ( cnt1 != cnt0 ){
                 test = false ; 
                 break; 
            }
            cnt1 = 0;
            cnt0 = 0;
    }
    if( test ) { 
         cout << "correct \n" ;
    }
    else {
        cout << "incorrect \n" ; 
    }
}
```

In the above algorithm, as you can see, you only need the length of the string `st0` and `st1` so you could just use 2 int variables and test the difference between the two, this way is more memory efficient as well as slightly faster run times.

Comment: This answer would benefit substantially from elaboration aside from comments embedded in large blocks of code. What was the OP doing wrong? How does this fix it?

Comment: Please don't throw a blob of code at the readers. Explain what was wrong and how you fixed it.

Comment: @Chris Thanks for the feedback! I'm still fairly new to the platform. I did change my answer, I would be grateful if you take a look at it and tell me how I can improve it.